# Porting a python 2 to python 3 serial file

Tags: python, encode, porting

I have issue porting a old python2 script to python3 that used to work pretty well. Here is the Python 2 code, its purpose is to create a command to send over serial:

```
def makeCommand(command, data=''):
    length = len(command) + len(data) + 1
    buf = [chr(length), chr(0xFF), command, data]
    checksum = 256 - sum[(ord(x) for x in buf)]%256
    buf.append(chr(checksum))

    return ''.join(buf)


def main():
    makeCommand('A')

main()
```

Python3, with a few updates:

```
def makeCommand(command, data=''):
    length = len(command) + len(data) + 1
    buf = [chr(length), chr(0xFF), command, data]
    checksum = 256 - sum[x for x in buf)]%256
    buf.append(chr(checksum))

    return ''.join(buf).encode()
```

Now, when I run them, I got:

- Python 2: **\x02 \xFFA \CRC**
- Python 3: **\x02 \xc3 \xbfA \CRC**

Python2 output was exactly what I expected, but I don't understand Python3 output. Why is my bytes splitted in 2 (\xc3 \xbf instead of \xFF), and same issue with the CRC.

How can I have the same output with Python3 ?

Thank you